# Why the type is System.Object here?

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, delegates, boxing

Here is some piece of code :

```
Func<dynamic> f1 = new Func<dynamic>(() => 10);
Func<int> f2 = () => 10;

Console.Write(f1.Method.ReturnType);
Console.Write(" and " + f2.Method.ReturnType );
```

Output : `System.Object and System.Int32`

My question is  :

Why `dynamic` type inferred by DLR (type that is used for `dynamic`) here is `System.Object` and is not `System.Int32` ? It's not very logical as it also involves boxing of the Int32 struct to object.

As far as i understand, when we check type here we do it dynamically on execution time because we use Reflection. So it's known to DLR by then that it's `int` but for some reason it boxes it into `Object`...  Why?

I've tried to find anything regarding this on SO and googled for it but I couldn't find any answer that explains it all.

Comment: not sure what is `f1.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First()` but better way to get return type is this `f1.Method.ReturnType`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary you're correct, we can do it both ways and it produces the same outpue Object, and Int32...  I don't understand why it's Object...

Comment: as Patrick Hofman said, the compiler does not know the type because the function `() => 10` is not executed yet.

Comment: No. To better understand try to cast, `(Func<int>)(() => 10)`. This is not assignable to `Func<dynamic>`. this means `Func<int>` and `Func<dynamic>` are completely different things. since `Func<dynamic>` is not executed the return type even in runtime is not known. If you execute it you will get correct result. try `f1().GetType()` and you see it prints System.Int32. The method information is saved inside `Method` property. that should be compile time. so `f1.Method.ReturnType` is object for dynamic and its Int for int

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thank you for your useful comments. I seem to be forgetting that the static compiler cannot infer type for lambda expression when it comes to dynamic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is inferred here. It just doesn't know the type until it executes, and that is why the type given is `object`. The (**static**) compiler doesn't know the type since you don't know it yet. It is passed around as `object` and on the calling side it is `dynamic` again.

This is the same for regular methods:

```
Console.Write(typeof(Program).GetMethod("F1").ReturnType);

public static dynamic F1()
{
    return 10;
}
```

Output:

> System.Object

Comment: Thank you Partick, you made a good point. I seem to be confused alittle in how `dynamic` works with struct types in 'normal ways' and how it works with delegates

Comment: @Fabjan - Remember that `dynamic` isn't a type - it's just a declaration that the type is not known at compile time. The only type that the compiler can use to represent any type in the future is `object`. It's that simple.